# Errors while using using dual monitors on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, thinkpad

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Thinkpad P51.

When I connect an external monitor Thinkvision 2550x1440 using Usb-c, it works fine.

But when I try to connect a second monitor, a Thinkvision 1920x1024 using HDMI and try to enable it via Display, there is an error.

Display settings and error messages that appear after click Apply:

[image]

[image]

[image]

NOTE: Attaching only 1 screen work fine (any of 2), but not both together.